# converting entire sentence into string into list without split

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to convert a sentence into list format without space separator
I tried the following way

```
a = 'this is me'
```

when I am using split to get into list format

```
a.split(' ')
# ['this', 'is', 'me']

list(a)
# ['t','h','i','s','m','e']
```

is there any way to give input as

```
a = 'this is me'
```

and get the output as

```
a = ['this is me']
```

Comment: Simply do `a = [a]`

Comment: What are your operations on the string? You should be able to use a string as a list of characters without any problem,

Answer (score 6):

Use this:-

```
>>> a = 'this is me'
>>> [a]
['this is me']
```

Using `list` made the function iterate on the string, which you didn't want. Use those big braces instead, as a list constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`a = 'this is me'`

`" ".join(a.split(" "))` will return `'this is me'` and if `a` has leading/trailing spaces  `a = ' this is me '`  you can use `" ".join(a.strip().split(" "))`

to get your solution do

```
a = [a.strip()]
```

Comment: OP asking for `['this is me']` not for `this is me`